# Какова разница между приставкой недо и частицей не с глаголом?

Tags: частица-не

Не понимаю, какова, например, разница между такими глаголами, как недоедать и не доедать.

По лексическому значению глагол доедать означает доведение действия до конца. Не доедать, следовательно, означает съесть не до конца.

А вот какое значение у слова недоедать, я не знаю. Эту тему вообще не понимаю. Если кто-то объяснит, то буду благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значение приставки НЕДО- неполнота качества, недостаточность действия по сравнению с нормой

Он не доел завтрак и убежал-не с глаголом доел, т.е. не довёл действие до конца.

Они в войну недоедали - ели, но  недостаточно, плохо питались.

Недоглядел за ребёнком - глядел, но недостаточно, невнимательно.

Недоплатили за работу-заплатили, но недостаточно, мало, неполно.

Не достал до полки - отрицание действия достал

Времени недоставало - время есть, но мало, недостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо. Немного стало понятнее, кажется.

Comment: Нехватает: 1)Ребёнок не хватает игрушку в тот же миг,когда ему её подарили; 2)Ребёнку нехватало игрушек в его детстве

Comment: Нет, здесь раздельно - не с глаголом ХВАТАТЬ, просто глаголы-омонимы. Не хватает игрушек  - от хватить - быть достаточным.

Comment: Людмила, вот парадокс: чувствую, что я прав, но не чувствую, что Вы не правы! Странно!

Comment: Просто здесь нет приставки НЕДО-, о которой идёт речь, просто отрицание достаточности игрушек.НЕ с глаголом, но глагол безличный, вот и появляются ассоциации слитности, ослабления глагольности.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. У Вас стезя - работать с трудными учениками.